# How to change the text in the flatlist items with improved performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, react.js, react-native

I am working on a react native android app that generates fancy text. Similar to this [Fancy Text Generator](https://coolsymbol.com/cool-fancy-text-generator.html)

For every letter being typed fancy text will be generated.

I implemented everything and it works perfectly however the performance is very slow. Whenever I write text, the fancy text changes very slow and gets slower when the text becomes very large. I think it is the problem with the flatlist being rendered everytime the text changes or maybe with my textgeneration function. I tried everything to optimize it but it was still noticably slower even in the final build of APK file.

Here is the function that generates the fancy text:

```
remap = () => {
let newtext = Array(51).fill("")
let regText = `${this.state.inputdata}` != "" ? `${this.state.inputdata}` : "example"
let normal = `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890`
let normal2 = `a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`
let normal3 = `a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0`

let lent = regText.length

for (var i = 0; i < regText.length; i++) {
  let sliced = regText.slice(i, i + 1)
  let indexed = normal.indexOf(sliced)
  let indexed2 = normal2.indexOf(sliced)
  let indexed3 = normal3.indexOf(sliced)
  if (normal.includes(sliced)) {
    newtext[0] += [...fonts.font24][indexed];
    newtext[1] += [...fonts.font15][indexed];
    newtext[2] += [...fonts.font26][indexed];
    newtext[3] += [...fonts.font23][indexed];
    newtext[4] += [...fonts.font14][indexed];
    newtext[5] += [...fonts.font5][indexed]; //reverse remap
    newtext[6] += [...fonts.font4][indexed];
    newtext[7] += [...fonts.font25][indexed];
    newtext[8] += [...fonts.font0][indexed];
    newtext[9] += [...fonts.font21][indexed];
    newtext[10] += [...fonts.font22][indexed];
    newtext[11] += [...fonts.font19][indexed];
    newtext[12] += [...fonts.font18][indexed];
    newtext[13] += [...fonts.font17][indexed];
    newtext[14] += [...fonts.font16][indexed];
    newtext[15] += [...fonts.font2][indexed];
    newtext[16] += [...fonts.font20][indexed];
    newtext[17] += [...fonts.font6][indexed];
    newtext[18] += fonts.font3[indexed3] + fonts.font3[indexed3 + 1] + fonts.font3[indexed3 + 2];
    newtext[19] += [...fonts.font1][indexed];
    newtext[20] += [...fonts.font27][indexed];
    newtext[21] += [...fonts.font28][indexed];
    newtext[22] += [...fonts.font7][indexed];
    newtext[23] += [...fonts.font11][indexed];
    newtext[24] += [...fonts.font10][indexed];
    newtext[25] += [...fonts.font13][indexed];
    newtext[26] += fonts.font8[indexed2] + fonts.font8[indexed2 + 1];
    newtext[27] += [...fonts.font9][indexed];
    newtext[28] += [...fonts.font12][indexed];
    newtext[29] += normal[indexed] + '̲';
    newtext[30] += normal[indexed] + '̶';
    newtext[31] += normal[indexed] + '͙';
    newtext[32] += normal[indexed] + '̟';
    newtext[33] += normal[indexed] + '̃';
    newtext[34] += normal[indexed] + '͎';
    newtext[35] += normal[indexed] + '̺'; 
    newtext[36] += normal[indexed] + '͆';
    newtext[37] += normal[indexed] + '̳';
    newtext[38] += normal[indexed] + '̈';
    newtext[39] += normal[indexed] + '̾';
    newtext[40] += normal[indexed] + '͓̽'; 
    newtext[41] += normal[indexed] + '̸'; 
    newtext[42] += normal[indexed] + '҉ ';
    newtext[43] += normal[indexed] + '҈ ';
    newtext[44] += [...fonts.font29][indexed];
    newtext[45] += [...fonts.font30][indexed];
    newtext[46] += [...fonts.font31][indexed];
    newtext[47] += [...fonts.font32][indexed];
    newtext[48] += [...fonts.font33][indexed];
    newtext[49] += [...fonts.font34][indexed];
    newtext[50] += [...fonts.font35][indexed];
  }
  else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++)
      newtext[i] += sliced.toString();
  }
}
newtext[5] = newtext[5].split('').reverse().join('')
return newtext }
```

And here is my flatlist code:

```
 <FlatList
      ref={component=> this._MyComponent=component}
      style={{ marginTop: 10 }} 

      data = { this.remap() } //<--Function is called here on every change in text. 
      initialNumToRender={10}
      keyExtractor={( item, index) => 'key' + index}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
        (
          <TouchableHighlight underlayColor={'#ecf0f1'} style={styles.flatview} onPress={this.getListViewItem.bind(this, item)}>
            <View style={styles.Listviu}>
              <Text numberOfLines={1} ellipsizeMode="head" style={styles.item}>
                {item}
              </Text>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton.bind(this, item)}>
                <Icon name="copy" size={28} color="#7966FE" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.shareit.bind(this, item)} style={{paddingLeft: 4}}>
                <Icon name="share-2" size={28} color="#7966FE" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight> 
        )
      }
    />
```

Here is how my app looks like:

[image]

I have the unicode data in the seperate JSON file which is used by the function.

```
{
"font0": "αвc∂εғgнιנкℓмησρqяsтυvωxүzαвc∂εғgнιנкℓмησρqяsтυvωxүz1234567890",
"font1": "ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ１２３４５６７８９０",
"font2": "ⓐⓑⓒⓓⓔⓕⓖⓗⓘⓙⓚⓛⓜⓝⓞⓟⓠⓡⓢⓣⓤⓥⓦⓧⓨⓩⒶⒷⒸⒹⒺⒻⒼⒽⒾⒿⓀⓁⓂⓃⓄⓅⓆⓇⓈⓉⓊⓋⓌⓍⓎⓏ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨⓪",
"font3": "‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0",
"font4": "αɓc∂εƒɠɦเʝҡℓɱɳσρφɾรƭµѵωϰყƶαɓc∂εƒɠɦเʝҡℓɱɳσρφɾรƭµѵωϰყƶ1234567890",
"font5": "ɐqɔpǝɟƃɥᴉɾʞlɯuodbɹsʇnʌʍxʎz∀ᗺϽᗭƎℲ⅁HIſꞰꞀꟽNOԀΌꞞS⊥ᑎΛMXʎZ1234567890",
"font6": "ᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘϙʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢᴀʙᴄᴅᴇғɢʜɪᴊᴋʟᴍɴᴏᴘϙʀsᴛᴜᴠᴡxʏᴢ1234567890",
"font7": "ᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖᵠʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻᵃᵇᶜᵈᵉᶠᵍʰⁱʲᵏˡᵐⁿᵒᵖᵠʳˢᵗᵘᵛʷˣʸᶻ₁₂₃₄₅₆₇₈₉₀",
"font8": "aⷮbⷥcͩdͯeⷦfͩgⷬhⷮiͭjⷭkͪlⷨmͥnⷬoͤpͣqⷬrͤsͫtͨuⷬvⷦwⷦxͪyͭzͭaⷮbⷥcͩdͯeⷦfͩgⷬhⷮiͭjⷭkͪlⷨmͥnⷬoͤpͣqⷬrͤsͫtͨuⷬvⷦwⷦxͪyͭzͭ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0",
"font9": "卂乃匚ⅅ乇千G卄丨丿Ҡㄥ爪几ㄖ卩Ɋ尺丂ㄒ凵V山乂ㄚ乙卂乃匚ⅅ乇千G卄丨丿Ҡㄥ爪几ㄖ卩Ɋ尺丂ㄒ凵V山乂ㄚ乙1234567890",
"font10": "⒜⒝⒞⒟⒠⒡⒢⒣⒤⒥⒦⒧⒨⒩⒪⒫⒬⒭⒮⒯⒰⒱⒲⒳⒴⒵⑴⑵⑶⑷⑸⑹⑺⑻⑼⒪",
"font11": "ค๒ς๔єŦgђเʝкl๓ภ๏ρợгรtยѵฬϰՎzค๒ς๔єŦgђเʝкl๓ภ๏ρợгรtยѵฬϰՎz1234567890",
"font12": "₳Ƀ€ƉɆ₣₲ĦƗɈԞⱠM₦Ø₱QɌ$₮ɄV₩Ӿ¥Ƶ₳Ƀ€ƉɆ₣₲ĦƗɈԞⱠM₦Ø₱QɌ$₮ɄV₩Ӿ¥Ƶ1234567890",
"font13": "äḅċďệḟġḧïjḳŀṃńöṗqŕṩẗüṿẅẍÿẓÄḄĊĎỆḞĠḦÏJḲĿṂŃÖṖQŔṨṮÜṾẄẌŸẒ1234567890",

"font14": "",
"font15": "1234567890",
"font16": "",
"font17": "",
"font18": "1234567890",
"font19": "ℎ1234567890",
"font20": "1234567890",
"font21": "❶❷❸❹❺❻❼❽❾⓿",
"font22": "ℭℌℑℜℨ1234567890",
"font23": "1234567890",
"font24": "",
"font25": "ℂℍℕℙℚℝℤ",
"font26": "ℯℊℴℬℰℱℋℐℒℳℛ1234567890",
"font27": "1234567890",
"font28": "1234567890",
"font29": "1234567890",

"font30": "ꋫꃃꏸꁕꍟꄘꁍꑛꂑꀭꀗ꒒ꁒꁹꆂꉣꁸ꒓ꌚ꓅ꐇꏝꅐꇓꐟꁴꋫꃃꏸꁕꍟꄘꁍꑛꂑꀭꀗ꒒ꁒꁹꆂꉣꁸ꒓ꌚ꓅ꐇꏝꅐꇓꐟꁴ1234567890",
"font31": "ᗩᗷᑕᗪEᖴGᕼIᒍKᒪᗰᑎOᑭᑫᖇᔕTᑌᐯᗯ᙭YᘔᗩᗷᑕᗪEᖴGᕼIᒍKᒪᗰᑎOᑭᑫᖇᔕTᑌᐯᗯ᙭Yᘔ1234567890",
"font32": "ДБCDΞFGHIJҜLMИФPǪЯSΓЦVЩЖУZДБCDΞFGHIJҜLMИФPǪЯSΓЦVЩЖУZ1234567890",
"font33": "ąβȼď€ƒǥhɨjЌℓʍɲ๏ρǭя$ţµ˅ώж¥ƶąβȼď€ƒǥhɨjЌℓʍɲ๏ρǭя$ţµ˅ώж¥ƶ1234567890",
"font34": "ÃβČĎẸƑĞĤĮĴЌĹϻŇỖƤǪŘŜŤǗϋŴЖЎŻÃβČĎẸƑĞĤĮĴЌĹϻŇỖƤǪŘŜŤǗϋŴЖЎŻ1234567890",
"font35": "ᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾᵟᴿˢᵀᵁᵛᵂˣᵞᶻᴬᴮᶜᴰᴱᶠᴳᴴᴵᴶᴷᴸᴹᴺᴼᴾᵟᴿˢᵀᵁᵛᵂˣᵞᶻ1234567890"}
```

Here is the entire [Code](https://github.com/AzizStark/Quiva/blob/master/App.js).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < regText.length; i++) {
  // ...
  if (normal.includes(sliced)) {
    newtext[0] += [...fonts.font24][indexed];
    newtext[1] += [...fonts.font15][indexed];
    newtext[2] += [...fonts.font26][indexed];
    // many more
```

For *every character* of the input, you're spreading *every font* into a new array. With 28 fonts and 40 characters, that's 1120 arrays that need to be created. before `remap` is done - and each of those arrays is a font, so it has to iterate through all characters in the font for each such array.

If the `fonts.font` properties are array-like structures, there should be no need to spread:

```
newtext[0] += fonts.font24[indexed];
newtext[1] += fonts.font15[indexed];
newtext[2] += fonts.font26[indexed];
```

If they're *not* array-like structures, and you really do have to invoke their iterators, invoke the iterators *once*, at the beginning of the app, rather than on every new input, for every character, see the next code block.

In order to have the `fontArrays` be persistent over the lifetime of the app, but still only scoped to the `remap` function, you can make it into an IIFE:

```
remap = (() => {
  const fontArrays = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    fontArrays.push([...fonts['font' + i]]);
  }
  return () => {
    const newtext = Array(51).fill("");
    // ...
  };
})();
```

Then, replace the lines like

```
newtext[0] += [...fonts.font24][indexed];
newtext[1] += [...fonts.font15][indexed];
newtext[2] += [...fonts.font26][indexed];
```

with

```
newtext[0] += fontArrays[24][indexed];
newtext[1] += fontArrays[15][indexed];
newtext[2] += fontArrays[26][indexed];
```

If at all possible, it would also be good to change the definition of your `fonts.font#` properties such that they're an array of fonts, rather than an object of numeric-indexed properties. That is, to reference a font, it'd be nice to be able to do

```
fonts[24]
```

instead of

```
fonts.font24
```

Other possible improvements to the code:

[Always use `const`](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75) when possible, never use `var`, use `let` only when `const` can't be used - `const` makes the code more readable, when a reader can be sure that a variable name won't be reassigned.

There's no need to use a template literal to interpolate a single variable and nothing else, as you're doing with:

```
let regText = `${this.state.inputdata}` != "" ? `${this.state.inputdata}` : "example"
```

Given how you're using it, it looks like `inputdata` it's already a string, so instead use

```
const regText = this.state.inputdata || 'example';
```

(if it's not already a string, call `String` on it: `String(this.state.inputdata) || 'example'`)

If you're going to use semicolons (which is a great idea unless you're determined *not* to use them and are experienced enough to avoid ASI pitfalls), best to use them everywhere - it's good to pick a style and be consistent. Consider using a linter like [ESLint](http://eslint.org/). (If you don't, and you accidentally miss adding a semicolon or few, you'll occasionally run into [weird bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050219/es6-array-destructuring-weirdness))

`String.prototype.includes`, like `indexOf`, has `O(n)` complexity. The interpreter has to search through *every character* of the string to see if there's a match. Since you're already checking `normal.indexOf(sliced)`, how about comparing that against `-1` instead of using `.includes` to do the same thing again?

You can also use the string iterator instead of a `for` loop, making the code a bit prettier.

It would also be nice not to have the horribly repetitive listing of indicies to `+=` to `newtext`. Consider creating an array of font indicies that are iterated over first, to replace all the `+= [...fonts.font24][indexed];`. Afterwards, you can insert the *other* parts which don't conform to that pattern, like for `newtext[18]` and `newtext[26]`.

```
const fontOrder = [24, 15, 26, 23, 14, 5 /* ... */ ];
// these are the characters to for newtext[30] to newtext[43]
const otherChars = ['̲', '̶', '͙', '̟', '̃', /* /* ... */ ]
const otherCharsNewText = otherChars.map(() => '');

// define these out here so we're not splice-ing on every iteration below
let insertAt18 = '';
let insertAt26 = '';
for (const char of regText) {
  const indexed = normal.indexOf(char);
  if (indexed !== -1) {
    const indexed2 = normal2.indexOf(char)
    const indexed3 = normal3.indexOf(char)

    fontOrder.forEach((fontIndex, i) => {
      newtext[i] += fontArrays[fontIndex][indexed];
    });

    // Then insert the other parts:
    // use slice instead of concatenating indicies:
    insertAt18 += fontArrays[3].slice(indexed3, indexed3 + 3);
    insertAt26 += fontArrays[2].slice(indexed2, indexed2 + 2);

    otherChars.forEach((char, i) => {
      otherCharsNewText[i] += normal[indexed] + char;
    });
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
      newtext[i] += char;
    }
  }
}
// Then insert the insertAt18, insertAt26, and otherCharsNewText into the newtext:
newText.splice(18, 0, insertAt18);
newText.splice(26, 0, insertAt26);
newText.splice(29, 0, ...otherCharsNewText);
```